# How could I display images in a vue component throught laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I save an image with Laravel and want to display it on another page with vue.

I'm passing the entire object as a prop to vue, so it can access its name.

The problem is, when I do

```
$img = $request->file('image')->store('public/product_images');
```

sure, the image is saved into `storage/app/public/product_images`, but it's stored as `public/product_images/UZ9bLK65CwOWDoB002rt61y1PyldZ4iEWpKh5HHl.jpg` in the database, and is accessible through `http://localhost:8000/storage/product_images/UZ9bLK65CwOWDoB002rt61y1PyldZ4iEWpKh5HHl.jpg`.

So basically the vue component gets `public/product_images/UZ9bLK65CwOWDoB002rt61y1PyldZ4iEWpKh5HHl.jpg` as the image (as `product.image`), this way it's not accessible.

How am I supposed to pass the image link to the vue component and display it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised about 30 minutes ago that I messed it up.

Instead of

```
$img = $request->file('image')->store('public/product_images');
```

I should've used

```
$img = $request->file('image')->store('product_images', 'public);
```

This way it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full path of the file via an accessor or manually appending the fullpath when accessing through controller.
The following code will return the entire path:

```
Storage::url($filePath);
```

`$filePath` is the path you're getting back when storing the file.

So, your code will be:

```
$storagePath = $request->file('image')->store('public/product_images');
$filePath = Storage::url($storagePath);
```

Comment: Is that safe to do?

Comment: Yes, obviously.The storage keeps files protected. Normally hashed or random strings are used for filenames. So, even in case somebody knows the path of files. He cannot find the exact one.

Comment: In case this answers your question, accept the answer as the correct one so it may help the others who are looking for the same question.

Comment: I ticket the other answer, I realized where I screwed up. Idk if the code you sent would solve the problem I encountered in the main question, but the one I sent 100% solves it.

Answer (score 0):

$storagePath = $request->file('image')->store('public/product_images');
$filePath = Storage::url($storagePath);

Comment: The actual answer was already posted.